# Generate Graphs with multiple requests with 500 odd users in Jmeter?

Tags: graph, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-3.2

Currently i have nearly 35 request sampler to accomplish a complete task in app using Jmeter and its working perfectly. But however i need to see the Graphs of the same for 500 requests either in Histogram / Pie chart or in line chart to analyse the same.

Is there any way to accomplish the same in Jmeter ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the graph you want in [JMeter dashboard](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Two option of generation dashboard:

> Generation from an existing sample CSV log file
>
> ```
> jmeter -g <log file> -o <Path to output folder>
> ```
>
> Generation after load test
>
> ```
> jmeter -n -t <test JMX file> -l <test log file> -e -o <Path to output folder>
> ```